# http://localhost forced into https://localhost when accessing duplicated wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, https, localhost, cloudways

I am using Duplicator Pro to duplicate a wordpress site from cloudways to my localmachine. After I finished the duplication process, and I enter http://localhost/mysite in the browser, the browser (both Chrome and Safari) change the protocol from "http" to "https", and ofcourse, it can't find the site. Has anyone run into this problem. And it only happens for this particular "mysite" wordpress directory. I have various wordpress folders in my ~/Sites/  folder in my Mac, but I can access all the other wordpress sites locally with http://localhost  . But I cannot access this particular "mysite" wordpress directory with just "http". Is there some kind of file that perhaps Apache is looking into that says to redirect http to https when this particular "mysite" is being referenced?

Thanks

Comment: I figured it out. An ssl security plugin was rewriting http access to https in the .htaccess file , so I removed the plugin and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the database if site url or home url has https. and try disabling all plugins.